# My files! Can I save forms, locally against secured pages?

Tags: browser

I'm using a company website, and the Internet has become very spotty, due to an internal issue.  When the Internet crashes, I get an error message from the site.  Pressing the back button or refresh button reproduces the error.  So, I have to close my browser (Chrome, latest), and log back into the site!

Typically, we lose 45 minutes of work (about twice a day).  There are times, however, when hours of progress are lost!  And sometimes it's difficult to reproduce data (for example, when we get data from a customer and the submit button fails after the customer has left our offices).

Is there a way to temporarily save all the form data on a page (like an add-on with a button I can just press, "Save current progress on this page."), and then have the data automatically resubmitted by pressing it again, later?  Or perhaps, is there another work-around that I can work into my browser, locally?

I found this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/form-history-control/, but there are two issues:

1) Everyone here wants to stick with Chrome and not install and use another browser--stubborn people.

2) This doesn't seem to fit the exact purpose.  It uses 'the most recent values' and not saved values.

Comment: Have you already looked through the [search results for "form"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/form) in the Chrome Web Store? If they don't meet your requirements, and you want a tailored extension for your company, contact me to discuss the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Chrome Extension like [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno/reviews) should be a decent fit.

[image]

Comment: You're a ba~d man, Sath.  Thanks.  You and the developer are saving us a lot of time.